# Sencha touch not showing a view using controller

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have the following code in my controller and am trying to simply switch a view.
Can anyone explain how to get the view to display.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.HomeController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        views: [
            'Home',
            'ChangeEmailView'
        ],

        refs: {
            changeEmailView: {
                selector: '#btnChangeEmail',
                xtype: 'ChangeEmailView'
            }
        }
    },

    init: function(application) {
        alert("init");
    },

    launch: function() {
        alert("launch");
    }

});
```

View:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ChangeEmailView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.ChangeEmailView',

    config: {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            ui: 'light',
            title: 'Change Email Address'
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be the following:

```
showChangeEmailView: function () {
    Ext.Viewport.add(this.getChangeEmailView());
    this.getChangeEmailView().show({
        type:'slide',
        direction:'up'
    });
}
```

[Here's an example](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#z1DaQ)

But then it really depends of your app structure. Maybe you're working with a NavigationView and then you need to push the view.

Hope this helped

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the show method. Updated my answer with a SenchaFiddle

Comment: So you have no controller, should i remove mine and replace with a button handler on the view?

Comment: No, you should keep your controller. It's always better to keep the logic, the code, separate from the view definition. I didn't use one in the SenchaFiddle because it would be a hassle to create a controller just to show you how to show a view.

Comment: But if you're still confused, I can do it with a controller.

Comment: Yes please, I swore I read somewere that xtype would autocreate the view somehow so wouldnt need to add to viewport. Can you maybe give example of possible ways of showing view? Thanks for ur help.